How to filter dictionaries twice by a unique first and second field?
I want to get a list of dictionaries from two lists, filtered by unique fields.
For example: I need to create key-value pairs in such a way that the elements from both lists are unique.
I'm trying to use a nested loop:
- name: "Create list"
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all

  vars:
    var1:
      - '1'
      - '2'
      - '3'
    var2:
      - 'a'
      - 'b'
      - 'c'

  tasks:

    - name: "Merge lists"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        new_list: "{{ new_list | default([]) + [{'var1': (item[0] | string), 'var2': (item[1] | string)}] }}"
      loop: "{{ var1 | product(var2) | list }}"

    - name: "Print new_list"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ new_list }}"

The result is as follows:
[
        {
            "var1": "1",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "1",
            "var2": "b"
        },
        {
            "var1": "1",
            "var2": "c"
        },
        {
            "var1": "2",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "2",
            "var2": "b"
        },
        {
            "var1": "2",
            "var2": "c"
        },
        {
            "var1": "3",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "3",
            "var2": "b"
        },
        {
            "var1": "3",
            "var2": "c"
        }
]

The desired result for me:
[
        {
            "var1": "1",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "2",
            "var2": "b"
        },
        {
            "var1": "3",
            "var2": "c"
        }
]

I tried to figure out the example from this query, but the case there is different from mine.
Update
Let me add some context to understand what I plan to use this for.
The first list contains the names of the virtual machines, the second list contains the names of the servers.
It is necessary to distribute the virtual machines evenly across the servers. I thought that in practice the number of elements in dictionaries may be different, for example:
var1: ['1','2','3','4','5']
var2: ['a','b','c']

And then in this example I would like to get this result:
[
        {
            "var1": "1",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "2",
            "var2": "b"
        },
        {
            "var1": "3",
            "var2": "c"
        },
        {
            "var1": "4",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "5",
            "var2": "b"
        },
]


Why not, for example, [{"var1":"1","var2":"b"},{"var1":"2","var2":"c"},{"var1":"3","var2":"a"}]?

According to your desired output, you can simplify the problem as in the following demo playbook:
---
- name: Manipulate lists
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    var1:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
    
    var2:
      - a
      - b
      - c

    new_list: >-
      {{
        dict(
          var1 | map('string') | zip(var2 | map('string'))
        ) 
        | dict2items(key_name='var1', value_name='var2')
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show calculated list
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: new_list

which gives:
PLAY [Manipulate lists] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show calculated list] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_list": [
        {
            "var1": "1",
            "var2": "a"
        },
        {
            "var1": "2",
            "var2": "b"
        },
        {
            "var1": "3",
            "var2": "c"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0


Your option works, thank you!
But I clarified my question at the beginning

Use community.general.dict. This declaration
    vms: "{{ var1 |
             batch(var2 | length) |
             map('zip', var2) | flatten(1) |
             map('zip', ['var1', 'var2']) |
             map('map', 'reverse') |
             map('community.general.dict') }}"

gives what you want
  vms:
    - {var1: 1, var2: a}
    - {var1: 2, var2: b}
    - {var1: 3, var2: c}
    - {var1: 4, var2: a}
    - {var1: 5, var2: b}



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    var1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    var2: [a, b, c]

    vms: "{{ var1 |
             batch(var2 | length) |
             map('zip', var2) | flatten(1) |
             map('zip', ['var1', 'var2']) |
             map('map', 'reverse') |
             map('community.general.dict') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: vms | to_yaml


